# BluetoothGatt.Connect not working when phone is not charging

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I build a foreground service and timer, it's will send some message to remoted device every 45secs. I really sure about service is working, and breakpoint also stop at BluetoothGatt.Connect() but OnConnectionStatusChanged never triggered when phone is not charging. I don't know it's a Android limit or Manufacturer limit.

anyone had same problem?

Comment: do you try with the screen off or on? Also does it stop working immediately or after some time?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko service will still working, but connect or writeChar method will be useless immediately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this, I only need call BLE method in main thread.

```
Handler handler = new (MainLooper);
handler.post(()=>{gatt.Connect();});
```